# unicode window title on windows

Tags: windows, python-3.x, unicode

I thought that in the 21st century this is not a problem, but:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui
print('\u2122')
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = QtGui.QWidget()
widget.setWindowTitle('\u2122')
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

on Ubuntu displays the trademark symbol in both the window and the terminal, on Windows (10) it displays `\u2122` both places. I am using `python 3.4` on both systems, on windows it's an Canopy install, if that helps anything, but probably totally unrelated to that. How can I get unicode characters to display on Windows as well?

**EDIT**

Okay, so it turned out that having `print()` doesn't make it python 3, my bad. Although the Windows python 2.7.9 gives an interesting error when I fix the strings to `u'\u2122`:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86\lib\encodings\cp852.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2122' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

Anyway, installing a 3.x will solve the issue.

Comment: Are you sure your Windows install is 3.x? The described behaviour would happen under Python 2.x. As a test, change the string to a 2.x Unicode string and see what happens. E.g. `u'\u2122'`

Comment: I am pretty sure because of the `print()` that should give me an error under python 2.x right? But I'll check :)

Comment: Nah, at some point `print()` became valid syntax in 2.x

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack, in 2.x `print()` is just printing an expression that's in (unnecessary) parentheses. It's not a function call. If you try `print('a', 'b')`, you'll see it parses and prints `('a', 'b')` as a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you have Python 3.x on your Windows box. The results are consistent with using Python 2.x.

To make your code with 2.x, change the strings into Unicode strings by appending a `u` to each one. E.g.

```
widget.setWindowTitle('\u2122')
```

On Windows, don't try to print Unicode to the console - it's totally broken. If you must, see the following module which allows it: https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console

Comment: is it also broken with powershell?

Comment: well, as soon as I have python3 running I'll find out :D

Comment: @fbence, cmd.exe, powershell.exe, python.exe -- these are all console programs that talk to a console window hosted by conhost.exe. PowerShell is not a terminal. There's PowerShell ISE, but CPython doesn't work correctly in that environment. Anyway, I wouldn't call Unicode broken in the console in general. It's broken in the way CPython tries to use it (using `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` via the C runtime `read` and `write`). win-unicode-console uses the wide-character APIs `ReadConsoleW` and `WriteConsoleW`; these work fine.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks, I didn't know that. I somehow thought that with powershell the windows world got a little closer to linux terminal-wise but it doesn't really seem so :)

Comment: hmm, I was reminded today about why I switched to ubuntu from windows :)